# Pass params in react native dynamic links

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, react-native-firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, universal-link

I'm using `@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links` to handle firebase dynamic links inside the react native app.

I've created a dynamic link `https://example.page.link/settings` and I'd like to have an option where I could click on the link that looks like `https://example.page.link/settings?account` or `https://example.page.link/settings?notifications` and it would take me to the account or notification screen inside the settings.

using:

```
dynamicLinks().onLink(async (link) => {
  console.log({ link });
});
```

when I click on `https://example.page.link/settings?account`,
I only receive an object that contains `url` (that doesn't contain params - just `https://example.page.link/settings`) and minimumAppVersion`.

I've noticed that if I create a short link inside the firebase console `https://example.page.link/settings` and in the second step I put `https://example.page.link/settings?account` as a deeplink, then when I click on a short link I would receive the link with `account` param, but that doesn't solve my problem as I would have to create a separate short link with different deeplink that has a hardcoded params

What is the right way to go with this using `Firebase dynamic links` if I want to see params inside my app, or for this use case I will have to go with a custom solution and not use firebase?

Answer (score 1):

For a nested navigations using Dynamic links, we can create a link in a way that we can access to navigate to the specific screen.

like, if we needed to navigate to the settings screen and then, the account screen or notifications screen then, we have to set the URL in a way to navigate to the specific screen.

have a try with the below link

```
https://example.page.link/settings/account
```

Instead of the previous try

```
https://example.page.link/settings?account
```

we are also able to use deep linking to open the specific screen with react-navigation.

checkout the official docs of react-navigation to implement deep linking:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/

Comment: Is deep linking different than universal linking? You seem to suggest trying with the universal link but the docs are for deep linking.

Comment: @jscul, Please check the blog https://www.digitaldoughnut.com/articles/2020/march-2020/deep-link-vs-universal-link-which-one-is-better#:~:text=What%20is%20the%20difference%20between,more%20performing%20for%20their%20needs.